# How do I dequeue a parent theme's CSS file?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

My parent theme (Starkers) adds a CSS file that I'm trying to remove (I want to use @import instead so I can override styles more easily). Starkers has the following in its functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_enqueuer' );

function script_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script( 'site', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/site.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'site' );

    wp_register_style( 'screen', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', '', '', 'screen' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'screen' );
}
```

I've tried the following in the child functions.php, but the link and script tags still show up in the head section.

```
add_action('init', 'removeScripts');
function removeScripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style('screen');
    wp_deregister_script('site');
}
```

I've double checked to see if they are hard coded in the parent header and they are not.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> I want to use @import instead so I can override styles more easily

Simply. Don't. Do. That.

You simply jump into the same hook and then deregister/dequeue the styles/scripts and throw in your custom ones.

```
function PREFIX_remove_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'screen' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'screen' );

    wp_dequeue_script( 'site' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'site' );

    // Now register your styles and scripts here
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PREFIX_remove_scripts', 20 );
```

The reason for dequeue-ing and deregistering the scripts is simple:

> Note that if you'd like to be able to use either of those handles (`'screen'` or `'site'`) after dequeuing them, you'll need to deregister them too. For instance: `wp_deregister_style( 'screen' );` and `wp_deregister_script( 'site' );` - *peterjmag*

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would either remove the parent theme's stylesheet and replace it with a child theme's stylesheet OR just remove the parent's stylesheet from ever being loaded.

Starker theme's functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_enqueuer' );

function script_enqueuer() {
    //...
    wp_register_style( 'screen', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', '', '', 'screen' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'screen' );
}
```

Remember the handle that they call the style, **'screen'**

### Replacing parent theme's with child theme's stylesheet

Starker-Child theme's functions.php:

```
function​ ​custom_starkers_styles() {

    //Remove desired parent styles
    wp_dequeue_style( 'screen');

    //Replace with custom child styles
    wp_register_style( 'screen-child',​ ​trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ). 'screen.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'screen-child​'​);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','custom_starkers_styles', 20 );
```

### Remove parent theme's stylesheet

Starker-Child theme's functions.php:

```
function​ ​remove_starkers_styles() {

    //Remove desired parent styles
    wp_dequeue_style( 'screen');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','remove_starkers_styles', 20 );
```

We give the child theme's *add_action()* a priority of 20 (default is 10) because we want it to run AFTER the parent theme has queued it up. The higher the priority, the later it will run. 20 > 10 so the child theme's action will always run after the parent theme has already executed.