# Free theme and css/bootstrap.css is not overridden in the child theme

Tags: css, child-theme, parent-theme

Why is wordpress still using the bootstrap.css from the parent theme, whenI have a child theme which (successfuly for other things) inherits the parent theme? I have the bootstrap.css settled in the child theme inside the same directory css/ and I can see in firebug that on the page the parent's bootstrap.css is still used.

Comment: WordPress will enqueue all the child theme styles and then enqueue all the parent theme styles. If you want to remove the parent theme style, you have to find out what handle they used to register the style and then call `wp_dequeue_style( $handle )` You also have to make sure this runs after the parent has enqueued their bootstrap

Comment: Its about how to handle function `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Here for your answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/65526/18731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to enqueue styles in child theme's function.php to override parents styles. if you want to completely removed parent's bootstrap css then use wp_dequeue_styles() function and enqueue new bootstrap css in child theme's function.php

http://wpsites.net/web-design/how-to-deregister-dequeue-style-sheets/