# My style in my child theme loads after the parent theme, but it breaks stuff: How do I load it before the parent theme?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm building my child theme, but including materialize css that I want to use, breaks the entire site when enqueued in **functions.php**. How do I change that?

```
function bla_enqueue_child_theme_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('cookie-font', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie');
    //wp_enqueue_style('datatables-css', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('materialize-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css', 0);
    wp_enqueue_style('cake-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', '', 1, 'all');

    wp_enqueue_script('new-jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('materialize-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js');
    //wp_enqueue_script('datatables-js', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bla_enqueue_child_theme_styles', -20);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly your website breaks when you enqueue matirialize's CSS? Some screenshots may help.

Comment: The materialize css library overrides the parent css. To negate this effect I want materialize to load first and the parent css later.

Comment: What is your parent theme? Is it publicly available somewhere? I think the answer to your question depends on how and when is that theme enqueueing its own styles.

Comment: Cake by codeopus, it's not free I'm affraid. However is there not some other hook or priority parameter? It would be kinda weird if that's impossible right

Comment: Maybe the theme is enqueueing its styles at a different time. That is, maybe they are calling `wp_enqueue_style` from a function attached to a different hook. If you can find where and when is the theme enqueueing its styles, then you could try, attaching your function to the same hook if they are using a different one, or, use the handle name of the parent theme's style to dequeue (`wp_dequeue_style`) the CSS, enqueue yours and then enqueue the parent theme's style again.

Comment: Will have a look, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55032/discussion-between-willington-vega-and-thomas-moors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I load it before the parent theme?

I think you are doing it right. If the parent theme is attaching the function responsible for enqueueing its styles to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, then your `bla_enqueue_child_theme_styles()` function must be being executed first (because you passed `-20` as priority) and your styles should be being included first in the page's source code.

The fact that Materialize's CSS rules are overriding the parent theme's may not be related to the order in which the stylesheets are being included, but to the specificity of the selectors being used in those stylesheets.

Cake is likely to be using some kind of CSS framework as well, either one developed by a third party or a custom one. In that case, is very likely that both Cake and Materialize are trying to solve the same problems, but using different methods, creating conflicts in the process.

Answer (score 1):

You could first **dequeue** the *parent stylesheet*, then **enqueue** the *child stylesheet* and finally **enqueue** the *parent stylesheet*.

**Dequeueing** the *parent stylesheet* should work like this:

```
function PREFIX_remove_scripts() {

    wp_dequeue_style( 'screen' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'screen' );

    wp_dequeue_script( 'site' ); // optional 
    wp_deregister_script( 'site' ); // optional

    // Now register your styles and scripts here 

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PREFIX_remove_scripts', 20 );
```

…as described in the answer to this question: "[How do I dequeue a parent theme's CSS file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65523/how-do-i-dequeue-a-parent-themes-css-file)"